# Abandoning coroutines

Tags: lua, coroutine

How bad is it in Lua 5.1 to never let a coroutine properly end? In other words, if a coroutine yields but I never resume it, does it leave a lot of state lying around until program completion?

```
cor=coroutine.wrap(somefunc)

while true do
   done=cor()
   if done then -- coroutine exited with "return true" 
       break
   else -- coroutine yielded with "coroutine.yield(false)"
       if some_condition then break end
   end
end

function somefunc()
    -- do something
    coroutine.yield(false)
    -- do some more
    return true
end
```

Depending on **some_condition** in the pseudocode above, the coroutine might never be resumed, and thus might never properly "end".

Could I do this to dozens of coroutines without having to worry? Is it safe to leave coroutines in this state? Is it expensive?

Comment: I don't know Lua at all, but if I were in your shoes, I would want to know the bigger question: how can you determine if you are leaking memory (or whatever you're interested in when you say "expensive")? If there's a tool, for instance, then you can answer the question empirically yourself.

Comment: That would work for assessing the memory consumption element, but I was also wondering if it was safe. I.e. would it create later unforeseen problems?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The garbage collector can easily determine that the coroutine is unreachable and collect it. I don't know if any of the docs state that this will happen, but I tried the "empirical method":

```
while true do
  local cor = coroutine.wrap(function() coroutine.yield(false) end)
  cor()
end
```

Memory usage did not grow over time.

*Edit:* Google says:

[There is no explicit operation for deleting a Lua coroutine; like any other value in Lua, coroutines are discarded by garbage collection.](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/docs/corosblp.pdf) (Page 4 in the PDF)